# Can I use python to run/use applications on my Mac?

Tags: python

What I want to do is write a program in python that will automatically turn on and off my Phillips Hue lights from my Mac. Is there a way to make python use a downloaded application from the app store, or can it bypass that altogether and contact the lights directly over my wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make python use a 
>   downloaded application from the app store

You can't run iOS apps on a Mac.

> can it bypass that altogether and contact the lights
>   directly over my wifi?

The [Hue API is documented](https://developers.meethue.com/philips-hue-api) by Philips on the [developer website](https://developers.meethue.com/).

You certainly don't need an iOS app to control your lights.  A Python program can interact with the Hue bridge to control your lights also.  The Hue Bridge provides a REST API that you send requests to.  To access the API, you need a Python HTTP client, like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org).

You should also look at the free Python libraries for Hue API.  There are many available on PyPI (20+ available).  Using a library will save you the trouble of working directly with the REST API and the details of HTTP.  The library author has done all the hard work for you already.

You can `pip` install any PyPI package onto your Mac.  Check out some of the ones here: [Index of Packages Matching 'philips hue'](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=philips%20hue&submit=search)